# How to synchronize multiple instances of a stored procedure executing at the same time in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

Overview:
In my scenario a user uploads an excel file that needs to be written into database, I am allocating each uploaded file a batch_id   that batch_id is written in last column of each row of my table as shown in these pictures  [image: File of User 1]

[image]

With the help of this batch_id column I will be able to segregate that which rows belong to which document.(for example: if batch_id=1 than these 1000  rows belongs to document 1)

Problem:
Consider two users user1 and user2 executing this stored procedure at the same time while Stored Procedure  is writing batch_id=1 in all the rows which belong to document1,at the same time rows belonging to  document2 will gets inserted thus causing a conflict wether to write batch_id=1 or batch_id=2 in the rest of remaining rows.

Imperfect  Solution:
To Execute Stored Procedure on one document at a time,when its done execute it on document 2 but this will let the user to wait until the current execution finishes which i don't want to  happen.

Comment: Next week, when you look at the database, how do you know which document "1" means?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: @jarlh It was a mistake,please explain how this could have been achieved in case of MYSQL.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall'  The batch_id column has a foreign key reference to a parent table which have attributes like (id,user_id,user_name,status,batch_id) with the help of parent table i can identify who uploaded those rows.

Comment: Edit your question to be consistent. Don't say SQL Server in the subject line while you have tagged MySQL. That's one dbms too many.

Comment: @jarlh i have removed MYSQL tag.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Please Provide a solution

Answer (score -1):

You can always execute single SP in parallel. It will not impact the Logic. Please try.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Use the link "add a comment" to ask these kinds of questions.

Comment: Please write this in comments section much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks..!! I do not have 50 reputation points yet to add to the comment to Question.